# Updating SRID (Update_GeometrySRID) does not alter polygons (when it should)

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0, srid, shp2pgsql

I am trying to change the SRID of polygons layer, but I'm having trouble visualizing the result.

I the SRID is misreported the shapefile I used to import into PostGIS. The metadata says the reference system is SIRGAS2000(srid 4674). However looking how the data is "drifted" ([see image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9664dxx9k8lmdy/Savador_Brasil_OSMstreets_vs_EnumerationDistrictPolygons.PNG?dl=0)) I suspect the true SRID could be 4618 (SAD69)

So I tried updating the SRID (without changing the underlying points, etc) in Postgis:

```
CREATE TABLE setor_censitario_2 as select * from setor_censitario

SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('setor_censitario_2','geom',4618)
```

and compared the results of the SRID update polygons to to the original polygons in Qgis.

Nothing changed, both layers seem identical.

This puzzled me. Shouldn't they have changed? The parameters of the two "data" (SIRGAS2000 and SAD69) are indeed different in a non-negligible way. So, just to make sure the change of SRID was not supposed to be innocuous, I ST_Tranformed the geom:

```
create table setor_censitario_4 as 
  select geom, ST_Transform(geom,4291) as geom4291Transf, ST_Transform(geom,4618) as geom4618Tranf
    from setor_censitario
```

now the new geom is different from the original one. ST_Transform, of course, is not the correction I want (in fact I doubled the magnitude of the problem).

So why is Update_GeometrySRID not changing the location of the polygons in Qgis?

The shapefile is available from:
ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/censo_2010/setores_censitarios/ba.zip
after unziping I imported with:

```
shp2pgsql -c -s -I -W LATIN1 file public schema.table ...
```

UPDATE:

- following the [UpdateGeometrySRID help](https://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html) I also tryed:

  ```
   CREATE TABLE setor_censitario_3 as select * from setor_censitario
   ALTER TABLE setor_censitario_3 
     ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 4326) 
        USING ST_SetSRID(geom,4326);
  ```

results are the same (polygons in Qgis do not move)

UPTADE 2:

I also tried updating the SRID directly in PostGIS, but that did not change the position of the polygons.

To reproduce the situation directly in Ggis, download this file:
ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/censo_2010/setores_censitarios/ba.zip
unzip and open 29SEE250GC_SIR.shp in Qgis.

Then add an Open Street Maps Streets layer to the background (I haven't done it but I think it can be done, either by **Vector>Open Street Map > Download Data** of with the Open Layers Plugin). Or a satellite image from google (also Open Layers).

Zooming to around this location: lon -38.47761, lat -13.01077, Scale 1:8000 you should see something similar to this image:

- Green: polygons I want to correct. The perimeters of those should be defined by some of streets (polygons can include more than one city block though).
- Red: underlying OSM streets (which I assume are correct)
  [image: dislocated_polygons]

notice how the green layer is dislocated "northeast" from the red one.

UPDATE 3: changing the SRID to other projections **does** alter the polygons position. For example, changing the SRIDs from 4674 (Sirgas 2000) to 4225 (Córrego Alegre, also an older Brazillian projection) shifts the polygons south some 50m. It is only in the particular case of 4674 to 4618 that they don´t move.

Comment: would it be possible to re-import the shapefile using the `-s SRID` switch of shp2pgsql instead of trying within PostGIS?

Comment: @christoph: Tks for the suggestion. I  added  "-s 4618" to shp2pgsql and reimported. But the resulting layer is still the same (also dislocated from the roads network)

Comment: I just noticed that to me EPSG:4291 and EPSG:4618 look like pretty much identical: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4291/prettywkt/ http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4618/prettywkt/. 
SIRGAS2000 is indeed EPSG:4674 http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4674/prettywkt/. I realise this does not answer your question, but may be a hint leading into the right direction?

Comment: @chistoph: Tks. You are right. EPSG:4291 and EPSG:4618  are the pre-1995 and post-1995 versions of SAD69, which used to be the official Datum of Brazil before Sirgas2000 (4674). I actually tested with both and results are similar (I omitted 4291 from the original question for brevity).

Comment: Do you check if external *georegister* procedure can make your shapefiles fit to the expected positions? (ex. using 5 control points can get good fit)

Comment: What are the results of `select srid from geometry_columns where f_table_name = 'setor_censitario'` and `select st_srid(geom) from setor_censitario`? (Using the table that should be correct, obviously.)

Comment: @Scro, results are the same for both commands. On the original geom (in table setor_censitario) it returns 4326. And on the second table (setor_censitario_2,on which the SRID was updated) it returns 4291 on both queries (I added group by st_srid(geom) to the end of the second query )

Comment: Does `ST_MinX(geom)` give the same results for a particular row from "setor_censitario" and "setor_censitario_2"?  If not, then a transform has occurred somehow.  If so, then we may suspect that QGIS is mishandling the SRID.

Comment: @Scro: The transformation has not happened. results are the same for ST_Xmin(geom) on the original and  altered table

Comment: In QGIS, right-click the layer with the updated SRID, select the `General` tab, and make sure that EPSG:4618 is indeed the selected coordinate reference system.  Also ensure that 'on the fly' is enabled from top menu: `Project -> Project Properties, CRS tab`.

Comment: @Scro, I tryed doing that in Qgis (same as answer bellow). Changing the projections in Qgis also does not change the polygons location.

Comment: See Update 2 above, which makes it easy to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to explore changing projections is just to work in QGIS.

Load both your datasets, and ensure your 'correct' one has the right coordinate system defined. Do this by double clicking on the layer, going to the general tab of the properties, and ensuring the coordinate reference system is set correctly.

[image: coordinate system]

Now ensure that you have enabled 'on the fly' reprojection. You can do this down the bottom right of the main view, or in the project properties. Check the box enabling on the fly reprojection, and use the same coordinate reference system as you did for your 'correct' layer.

[image: on the fly reprojection]

Now you've got a workspace that will reproject any added data into the same CRS as your main data. So add your 'uncertain' layer, and if you change the CRS of that layer (double click the layer, go to general, change the CRS) then it will be shifted into the same CRS as your workspace. And, so, if you choose the correct CRS, it will align.

Once you know what CRS it should be, then go to PostGIS and update it there. Or go back and load it with the '-s 4618' argument.

Comment: tks. I tryed that but the polygons also did not move. See my UPDATE 2 above

Comment: also: I tried shp2pgsql with the '-s 4618' switch and the polygons are also the same

Comment: I don't think you read my suggestion. Try changing the SRID in QGIS, play around with a few. Maybe call up someone involved with the original data.

Comment: My comment above was imprecise. I did follow your suggestion (changing the SRID only in Qgis) and the polygons position did not change when changing from SRIDs 4674 to 4618. However changing to another SRID,  from SRIDs 4674 to 4225 , **does** alter the polygons position.

Comment: How big the change should be? You can test the difference that is found by the Proj4 library between EPSG:4674 and EPSG:4618 with gdaltranslate `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4674 -t_srs epsg:4618
-38 -13  
-37.9996522521584 -12.9995504747745 22.3304213359952`. The difference is in the fourth decimal. Does it feel correct?

Comment: Hey @user30184, you can do it in GDAL or Proj4, but you can do it on the fly with QGIS. My suggestion above will allow for an interactive exploration of CRS, which is, in my view, an easier way to try to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Hey @alexgleith, I wrote gdaltraslate but meant the query tool gdaltransform. The usage example is correct. Getting exact numbers is as well good for troubleshooting while with interactive tool user can get a general view faster.